# Как передавать свой аргумент в функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Пишу свой плагин для форм отправки. Возник вопрос, как передавать свой аргумент, как это делается например в методе jquery

```
$('tut selector').each(function(item) {

})
```

Тут автоматом как-то передается аргумент `item`, который я могу использовать.

```js
;
(() => {
  class Validation {

    constructor(options) {
      this.fields = options.fields;
      this.formElement = document.querySelector(options.formSelector);

      this._checkRules = {
        phone: /^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/,
        mail: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/,

      }
    }

    init() {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this.fields) === '[object Array]') {
        this.fields.map((item) => {
          document.querySelector(item.fieldSelector).addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
            //target - DOM элемент, поле
            //item.text - Условие, по которому нужно проверять строку или регулярное выражение
            //item.required - Обязательное ли поле
            let failCallback = item.onFail ? item.onFail : this.onFail;
            const target = event.target;

            if (this.fieldTest(target, item.test, item.required) === false) {
              failCallback();
            } else {
              onSuccess();
            }

          })
        })
      } else {

      }
    }

    onSuccess() {

    }

    onFail() {

    }

    fieldTest(field, test = 'default', required = false) {
      if (required && field.value == '') {
        return false;
      }

      switch (test) {
        case 'phone':
          return this._checkRules.phone.test(field.value);
          break;
        case 'mail':
          return this._checkRules.mail.test(field.value);
          break;
        case 'message':
          return field.value.length < 5 ? false : true;
          break;
        default:
          return true;
          break;
      }
    }

  }

  var valide = new Validation({
    formSelector: 'form',
    fields: [{
        fieldSelector: '.name',
        test: 'name',
        required: true,

      },
      {
        fieldSelector: '.phone',
        test: 'phone',
        onFail: () => {
          alert('Коллбэк сработал');
        }
      },
      {
        fieldSelector: '.mail',
        test: 'mail'
      },
      {
        fieldSelector: '.ms',
        test: 'message'
      },
    ]
  }).init();

})();
```

Заодно буду благодарен, если укажите на какие-то возможные улучшения моего кода.

Comment: `func('свой агрумент')` аргументы в функцию передаються таким образом

Comment: Вам необходим пример того же что делает `jquery`?

Comment: @doox911, да...

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле в приведенном тобой примере из jQuery, в метод each ты передаешь анонимную функцию, а метод each уже как то вызывает ее и передаёт в нее нужные аргументы.

Если конкретнее то jQuery в этом примере выполнит следующие:

1. Получит коллекцию HTMLElement
2. Пробежиться циклом по коллекции, где для каждого его элемента вызовет переданную тобой анонимную функцию и в качестве аргумента передаст текущий элемент.

Для примера ты можешь сделать в своем классе метод

```
each(cb) {
    this.fields.forEach(function (field) {
        cb(field);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Который будет вызываться так если init() так же будет возвращать this

```
const validator = new Validator(/*arguments*/)
        .init()
        .each(function(field) {
            console.log(field)
     })
```

P.S this возвращается что бы последовательно вызывать методы.

Проверить на массив можно с помощью оператора instanseof Array.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Answer (score 0):

`test`, `callback` - аргументы функции.

`callback` - так же и функция обратного вызова.

При вызове функции `log()` мы передаём ссылку на функцию. Обязательно без оператора вызова функции `()`.

```js
// Просто выводит T
const echoT = () => console.log('() => t');

// Просто выводит T
function logT () {
  console.log('function t');
}

function log (text, callback) {
  console.log(text);
  callback();
}

log('test', () => {
  console.info('Отработал callback');
});

log('test', echoT);

log('test', logT);
```

Вызов обратной функции с аргументами:

```js
function log (text, callback) {

  let count  = 2;
  console.log(text);
  callback(count);
}
// Стрелочная функция
log('test', i => console.log(i));

log('test', function(i) {
  console.log(i);
});
```